# osm2pgsql doesn't run in a QGis plugin

Tags: qgis, python, openstreetmap, pyqgis, osm2pgsql

I have a problem with osm2pgsql when it runs in a qgis plugin. The function i use looks like this:

```
    osm2pgsql = "osm2pgsql -s -d {databaseName} -U {databaseUser} -H {databaseHost} -E {SRID_GEOMETRY} {osm_file}"\
        .format(databaseName=connParam[0],
                databaseUser=connParam[2],
                databaseHost=connParam[1],
                SRID_GEOMETRY=srid,
                osm_file=down_file)

    os.system(osm2pgsql)
```

When i run this function in the python console in QGIS it runs without a problem. But when this function is used in a plugin it doesent't work. The osm2pgsql function starts with the console output

```
 Using projection SRS 32632 (EPSG:32632)
 Setting up table: planet_osm_point
```

but then nothing happens and qgis freezes. When I close qgis the function starts running and finishes successfully.

Has anyone an idea why this happens?

Comment: Osm2pgsql requires a lot of CPU, RAM and temporary disk space. Can you control how much is available for the plugin? And whether it can open temporary files?

Comment: The osm file I use has a size of only 10 MB. The strange thing is that if i load it as a script it runs in ~10 sec successfully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just found a solution.

There is also an active psycop2 connection. When I commit it or close the connection before osm2pgsql runs and open it afterwards again it works.
Probably osm2pgsql can't access to the database if this connection is open.

Comment: That makes sense. osm2pgsql changes/deletes the database tables too. This might be blocked if another connection exists.